# Overriding "New" button with VF page(Flow) for objects with Record Types

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object with 2 record types, and there are 2 page layouts correspondingly. Now I have created a Flow to gather all the required fields(based on one of the record types) and create the object.
How can i override the "New" button for this object so that when the record type for which the flow was created is selected , the VF page with the flow shows up and when the other record type is selected the  corresponding page layout shows up ?

Or do i have to modify the existing flow and pass it the record type, and based on that change the screens ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like you may be able to create a new button that attaches to APEX code that will do the branching that you want either to launch the flow, or to redirect to the page layout that you are seeking.